# Granting full rights on all files (owned by su) within certain directory

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, chmod, chown

I got some trouble with a server situation, where i keep some configuration files in a sub-directory of a web project. Using my superuser account, i make changes to these files, which NetBeans commits for me, by uploading them.

But the client needs to be able to access and modify these files via ftp. I was able to run a `chown ftpuser *.*` and it worked, but only until i re-uploaded the file, after which it was again owned by me, and the client could no longer modify it.

How can i make these files modifiable by me **and** the client?

(It's Debian 6.0 running on Plesk 11)

Comment: Sounds like ["Maintain setgid bit (after bower install or gulp build)"](http://serverfault.com/q/593179/4276), ["Maintain setgid bit (after bower install or gulp build)"](http://serverfault.com/q/6895/4276) and ["What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?"](http://serverfault.com/q/357108/4276) from Server Fault.

Comment: I read through the links, but found nothing helpful in there for my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look up file-based ACLs (FACL), as they're made to do what you are looking to do.

The short version is you set the partition in question to track file-based acl permissions by editing your /etc/fstab and add the "acl": option:

`#example
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol02  /  ext3  defaults,acl   1 1`

Then you set the appropriate FACL on the directory you want the client to access:

`#set existing owner/group to rwx
chmod ug=rwX -R /some/ftp/directory`

`#set existing files/folders to rwx for ftpuser
setfacl -m u:ftpuser:rwX -R /some/ftp/directory`

`#set future files/folders to rwx for ftpuser
setfacl -dm u:ftpuser:rwX -R /some/ftp/directory`

(Note that we set the existing owner and group to rwx because FACLs are limited to the owning group's permissions.  There are other ways around this, but the easiest is just ensuring the owning group as rwx)

Links:
http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2007/12/basic-linux-permission-model-lets-you.html
http://retrop.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/enabling-file-acls-in-debian-6-access-control-lists/